# How to retrieve data from node.js to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to learn sending/receiving data from Ajax to node.js. I am able to send the data from ajax but not able to receive. Not able to solve the problem. That'd be great if someone can explain where I'm going wrong.

> Ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#searchdata', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
 url: location.pathname,
 method: 'POST',
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 processData: false,
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 success: function (data) {
                   var ret = JSON.stringify(data);
                   console.log('Success: '+JSON.stringify(data))
               },
               error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                   console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
               },
  });
  });
```

> node.js

```
    var myData = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        myData += data.toString();
    });
 response.writeHead(200, {
             'Content-Type': 'text/json',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
      response.end(myData);
      });
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the Ajax error handler?

Comment: Nope. I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Could you add a log in the success handler before 'JSON.stringify' and see if it is logging?

Comment: Hey I just tried, its not working

Comment: okay and what jQuery version do you use ?

Comment: The version is 3.2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191370/discussion-between-uniboi-and-boney).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this statement in the jQuery Ajax documentation:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use
>   jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

I believe you will need to change the code similar to as mentioned above in the documentation.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't give me any alert. It prints on the browser instead

Comment: It is working when I set text in the dataType. So I'm not formatting the JSON properly when sending from the server to .ajax?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Actually, I have solved the problem. I had to format the JSON properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked that the server/api you are posting to return a response (use postman)
2. Have you checked the headers for the request. You may need to add authorization headers(pretty common practice with public apis)
3. Have you appended a client_id, app_id or api_key onto the request
4. Have you authenticated your request (basically point 2/3)

2 and 3 should return a response, in either case, I would use postman to check. If postman should at the very least return a response. Check the headers and the http status header. If you are getting a 200 response, and no content back there is likely an issue with the route or server configuration

Ajax example
$(document).on('submit', '#searchdata', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

```
//Get form by id
var $form = #("#form_id");

//Form data
var formData = new formData($form);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:300/edit/11', //path to api
    method: 'POST',    //Method to use (GET by default)
    data: formData,    //The data to be posted
    dataType: 'json',   //Expected reponse format
}).done(function(res){ 
    //Results here can contain an error - this is common for custom error types
    //Test for custom error assuming in the format res.error
    if( typeof res.error == 'undefined'){
        console.log(res)
    }else{
        //You have an error
    }
}).fail(function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Also what are you using with node.js? expressjs? if it is express your response should be response.json(myData)

Comment: I'm using node.js and something is wrong with the JSON data that I'm sending from server.

Comment: and what is location.pathname? ie the actual url

Comment: Not using any frameworks and now I am able to successfully send data ie JSON array but the loop is not getting executed inside ajax done function

Comment: this is where a framework would make it really easy - express would simply be `route.('/path/', function(req, res, next){res.json(myData})`

Comment: either way ensure you are posting to the correct script. i cannot tell because your using a dynamically created path in location.pathname

Comment: Are you using http module?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but for now I am trying to learn the core modules node.js. now the only problem is loop not executed inside the .done/success function

Comment: have you looked at this example https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request